# Opening a dbm file

Tags: xml, postgresql, dbm, pgmodeler

I have been provided a file, called datamodel.dbm

Within that file, is a lot of XML.

It opens with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
CAUTION: Do not modify this file unless you know what you are doing.
         Unexpected results may occur if the code is changed deliberately.
-->
<dbmodel pgmodeler-ver="0.8.1" last-position="0,0" last-zoom="1"
     default-schema="public" default-owner="postgres">
<role name="xxxx"
      superuser="true"
      encrypted="true"
      password="********"
      sql-disabled="true">
</role>

<database name="xxxx" encoding="UTF8" lc-collate="en_US" lc-ctype="en_US">
    <role name="xxxx"/>
    <tablespace name="pg_default"/>
</database>

<schema name="public" protected="true" rect-visible="true" fill-color="#e1e1e1" sql-disabled="true">
</schema>

<extension name="postgis" cur-version="2.1.7">
    <schema name="public"/>
    <comment><![CDATA[PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions]]></comment>
</extension>
```

I am a SQL Server chap, and I believe this file has something to do with PostGres.

Is there a tool to open this file to render a data model? The fole contains hundreds of tables with all the meta data, relationships etc. But I have no way of opening this, except in XML.

Is there a way to open this file and render the data model so I can visually see what it looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pgModeler file. You can find more information at https://pgmodeler.io.